# Utilize if else loop in logical vector to distinguish three statuses of numerical values in R

Tags: r

I want to convert numerical value to logical vector and compare it 5, this is the output that I want ( I wanted to compare logical vector to logical object, then if else loop to low, optimal or high):

```
5,2,8,6,11,4,7

 5 is optimal.
 Caution: 2 is low.
 8 is high.
 6 is high.
 11 is high.
 Caution: 4 is low .
 7 is high.
```

I tried the following:

```
a<-c(5,2,8,6,11,4,7) #assign values to a vector
a3<-unlist(a, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
an<-as.numeric(a3) #convert to numeric
st5<-5   #set a reference 
st1<-as.logical(st5)  #convert to logical
suffice <-(n3 >= 5) #assign output of 7 True and False into a variable
cat("\n")
cat("5 is norm \n")
cat("Data: ", paste(shQuote(a), "pg", collapse=", "), "\n")
if(a > 5) {
    paste(co1, "is high \n") if (a = 5) {
        paste(a, "is optimal.\n")
        }
        else {paste("Caution:", a, "is low \n"))}
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
a<-c(5,2,8,6,11,4,7) #assign values to a vector
n=5 #assign your optimal value
ifelse(a==n, paste0(n, " is optimal."), ifelse(a>n, paste0(a, " is high."), paste0("Caution: ",a," is low.")))
```

Comment: Actually you don't need `lapply` since `ifelse` is vectorized. Remove the loop and replace `x` for `a`.

Comment: @locoGris thank you! but you are comparing numeric vector to numeric object, I wanted to compare logical vector to logical object, then if else loop to low, optimal or high! I'm learning, I appreciate the support. You many noticed 'st1<-as.logical(st5)  #convert to logical
suffice <-(n3 >= 5) #assign output of 7 True and False into a variable' . I already upvoted your answer. But I'd appreciate more support to reach my goal.

Comment: @Parfait I did not use lapply! but thanks for the comment!

Comment: @user432797, with `ifelse` and then `cat` +`paste` your exact desired output is generated: https://rextester.com/RIBHN17014. Not clear what else you need.

Comment: @Parfait I have large data set, I want the convert it TRUE and FALSE compared to a logical 5 (TRUE), this way I will be able to screen out faster without the need to loop every single value for the second step, let's say If 37% of the values are TRUE, then the code will loop in this 37% to get optimal or high, because low is already screen out in 63% in the first step. And I do actually appreciate your help!

Comment: `ifelse` can do that for you without *any* loop. Vectorized operations is the most optimal approach to take. Solution here answers *this is the output that I want*. Putting aside semantics of "logical vectors", what else do you need? BTW `ifelse` is different than `if...else`.